# How to add a new column and a constraint in one go?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, constraints, alter-table

I want to add a new column to an existing table.

I need it to emulate the enum type (in the way possible in SQL Server; with value constraints, that is).

The following doesn't work:

```
ALTER TABLE orders ADD [sent_to_panel] NVARCHAR(16) NULL;       
ALTER TABLE orders WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_orders] CHECK (([sent_to_panel]='invalidated' OR [sent_to_panel]='not_sent' OR [sent_to_panel]='sent'));   
ALTER TABLE orders ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_orders_sent_to_panel]  DEFAULT (N'not_sent') FOR [sent_to_panel]; 
ALTER TABLE orders CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_orders];
```

I'm getting an error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Invalid column name 'sent_to_panel'.

If I execute the first command on its own, though:

```
ALTER TABLE orders ADD [sent_to_panel] NVARCHAR(16) NULL;
```

The rest goes through.

So I suppose the problem is that the column isn't actually added yet (and thus not recognized by `ADD CONSTRAINT`) when trying to get it all done in one go.

The question is: how to make the script work properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE a (
    b int
);

ALTER TABLE a
  ADD c nvarchar(16) NULL
    , CONSTRAINT check_this CHECK (c IN ('invalidated', 'not_sent', 'sent'))
    , CONSTRAINT defaultify DEFAULT ('not_sent') FOR c
;

ALTER TABLE a
  CHECK CONSTRAINT check_this
;

DROP TABLE a;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I'll accept your answer when the system allows me. Was my interpretation of the root cause correct?

Comment: @KonradMorawski if you separate the individual queries in to separate batches (use the `GO` keyword in T-SQL: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx) then your original script would work. You assumption is essentially correct.